# Why does my code only write the last line?

Tags: python

I'm writing a list to file but it only writes the last line.

Here is my code. I'm on Python 2.7.

```
server=os.listdir('.') #contents of the current directory
for files in server:
    public_html = []
    if os.path.isfile(files) == True :
        pass
    elif os.path.isdir(files) == True :
        public_html.insert(0, files)
        print public_html
        f = open("index.html","w")
        f.write("<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n<title></title>\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/normalize.css'>\n<script src=''></script></head>\n<body>")
        for folder in public_html:
            print folder
            f.write("<a>" + folder + "<a/>" + "\n")
            f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tidier way of approaching the problem:

```
import os

LINK = '  <a href="{href}">{txt}</a>'

TEMPLATE = """<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{title}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{stylesheet}"/>
</head>
<body>
{content}
</body>
</html>
"""

def main():
    dirs = [fname for fname in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(fname)]
    dirs.sort()   # in alphabetical order

    content = "\n".join(LINK.format(href=os.path.abspath(dirname), txt=dirname) for dirname in dirs)

    with open("index.html", "w") as outf:
        fields = {
            "title":      "My Directory List",
            "stylesheet": "css/normalize.css",
            "content":    content
        }
        outf.write(TEMPLATE.format(**fields))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: (at least in Windows...) `os.listdir` returns a sorted list anyway. In fact, often `dirs.sort` won't do what you want since `"Z" < "_" < "a"` so you'll have `["Amazing","Names","Of","Zebras","_Zoology","_argh","bar","foo"]` which definitely doesn't LOOK sorted!!

Comment: im on linux it does not need to be sorted all it does his fetches the folder list makes a link and sends it to webkit webview  and creates a window using gtk its an easy front end for a web development machine.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do `open('path/to/file',"w")` it blanks the file before writing to it. This is called "write mode" and more info can be found [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Instead, open the file in "append mode" (`'a'`), like this:

```
...
elif os.path.isdir(files): # == True is redundant here
    public_html.insert(0,files)
    print public_html
    f = open('index.html','a')
    ...
```

In addition, you're trying to close your file object in every iteration through your `public_html` list! This won't work, and will probably throw exceptions when you try to call `write` on a closed object. Dedent that once so it's after your loop

```
for folder in public_html:
    print folder
    f.write("<a>" + folder + "<a/>" + "\n")
f.close()
```

THAT BEING SAID, I think you're mostly going about this the wrong way...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

directories = [dir_ for dir_ in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(dir_)]
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n<title></title>\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/normalize.css'>\n<script src=''></script></head>\n<body>")

for directory in directories:
    tag = soup.new_tag('a') # can do ('a', href='link/path')
    tag.string = directory
    soup.body.append(tag)
with open('index.html','w') as index:
    index.write(soup.prettify())
```

This is more useful because you can more-easily control the contents of the HTML, including throwing `href` on those `<a>`s!

Comment: I'd give you another upvote for BeautifulSoup, but I can't :-/

Comment: im going with BeautifulSoup was reading about it and think for this occasion his exactly what i need. tanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `f.close()` is inside the `for`. Should be outside

Comment: i usually do php this his my 1 python program still struggling with it

Answer (score 0):

this his the code i end up doing from the answers posted above also this version his ported to python 3.4 might be usefull to someone.

```
LINK = '<li class="{webapp_name}"><h2>{webapp_name}</h2><a href="{href}{webapp_name}/">       <img src="./assets/images/text-html.png"></img></a></li>'

TEMPLATE = """{document}
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <width></width><height></height>
   <title>My Web Apps</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{stylesheet}"/>
 </head>
   <body>
     <ul class="websites">
       {content}
     </ul>
   </body>
</html>
"""
def create_html():
   wrkDir = os.getenv('HOME') + ("/Documents/Workspace")
   directory = [folder for folder in os.listdir(wrkDir) if os.path.isdir(wrkDir)]
   directory.sort()   # in alphabetical order
   server_links = "\n".join(LINK.format(href='http://localhost/', webapp_name=directory_name)

 for directory_name in directory)
     with open("index.html", "w") as index:
         fields = {
        "document":    "<!DOCTYPE html>",
        "stylesheet": "assets/style.css",
        "content":    server_links
     }
     soup = BeautifulSoup(TEMPLATE.format(**fields))
     index.write(soup.prettify())

if __name__=="__main__":
    create_html()
```